# Realistic limits of a ''Growth Spurt''

Tags: internal-consistency, biology

A character of mine (a girl in case that detail matters a lot) is at the brink of entering (or already int he early stages of) puberty.

And apart from (due to story related circumstances) growing up quite quickly mentally i would like to also show her growing up physically.

To show this i wanted her to be quite a lot taller by the end of the story compared to the beginning.

In the the span of this story (which covers about a year give or take a month) she basically has to go from realistic height for her age (she is 15 so i made her 155cm / 5'08.) to nearly as tall as her older brother who is about 180cm / 5'11.

Is this a realistic growth spurt or completely impossible by human standards?

Comment: I'm not sure where to look this up, but I think human growth rate limits are far beyond this (perhaps up to 18" in a year with certain glandular issues related to gigantism). Hell, I think my own children might have managed 3" in one year or another at one point.

Comment: If as you say this is not even close to how much children can grow in a year i have to wonder how fast i could have this character growing those 25 centimeters.

Comment: be aware that groth spurts often come with problems; i know i had a lot of knee pain for a year at least when i was 14. i still have scars at knees and hips where i grew faster than my skin could keep up with.

Comment: @BlueDevil I suggest that if already a child over the age of 2 or so, the limits might well be measured in (low number of) feet instead of inches. As ths notes though, it wouldn't come without penalty, you're probably looking at some gigantism features at these extremes.

Comment: @JohnO What would you suggest as a maximum growth without negative penalties/side effects?

Comment: @BlueDevil Under 12", by quite a bit. Your 3" seems plausible, and we might find anecdotal cases of 6" increases that didn't have bad side effects, but I'd expect those to be atypical and approaching the limit, whatever it really was.

Comment: Boys and girls have different [growth curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_height#/media/File:Human_height_growth_per_month,_United_States.png). At 15 years of age, a girl is normally [already very close to her final adult height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Female_Stature_vs_Age.svg). If a girl begins growing visibly taller after the age of 15 then something is very strange and should be investigated ASAP.

Comment: oh yeah, at the "brink of puberty" and 15 are a bit incompatible for a girl.

Comment: I'm uncertain how this is worldbuilding, it seems to be a pure biology/medical question to me. Voting to close NAW.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane Real-world questions or questions that can be answered on other stacks are not off-topic on the WB.SE. The only requirement is to provide some worldbuilding context, which is done in this case.

Comment: @Otkin It's a really tedious argument to have again and again, but I'm sticking with he [dependency argument](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8488/clarification-concerning-a-loophole-in-the-real-world-question-policy) juxtaposed with the argument that: "A legitimate answer that is strictly the facts of the real world demonstrates the query had no worldbuilding dependency, and the question should have been asked elsewhere." The OP might as well have asked: (Cont).

Comment: "In my world, the characters don't walk much, they get inside these metal things that make roaring noises and smell bad, they pay tokens or show a card or give money, sit for a while, then press a button, the metal thing stops and they get out, is this possible?" - The issue I have is that there's no "Lacks research" close reason - which is what I would have used here.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane You are referring to a proposal for a change in an established policy. This proposal has not been received that well. Please see the original policy [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate).  || If you think that the question lacks research you should say this. However, you should consider the official SE policy: [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)

Comment: Well, if we're sticking with original policy then: "If a quick google search will answer your question it may not be worth posting a question on the site. Generally, querents are expected to demonstrate what has been tried and why it was not sufficient or did not work." - As per the rest of the network, show your attempt to answer the question in other words. I.e. lacks research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

> During the adolescent spurt in height, for a year or more, the velocity of growth approximately doubles; a boy is likely to be growing again at the rate he last experienced about age two. The peak velocity of height (P.H.V., a point much used in growth studies) averages about 10.5 centimetres per year in boys and 9.0 centimetres in girls (about 4 and 3.4 inches, respectively), but this is the “instantaneous” peak given by a smooth curve drawn through the observations. The velocity over the whole year encompassing the six months before and after the peak is naturally somewhat less. During this year a boy usually grows between 7 and 12 centimetres (2.75 and 4.75 inches) and a girl between 6 and 11 centimetres (2.35 and 4.35 inches). Children who have their peak early reach a somewhat higher peak than those who have it late. ([Source](https://www.britannica.com/science/human-development/Increase-in-body-size))

You're advocating a growth spurt of 3 inches, which is less than the *maximum average* for girls of 4.35 inches.

But, just to be sure, the total for girls is 2.35–4.35 inches. Your "average average" is therefore 3.35 inches — still more than you're looking for.

And remember, that article says this is just the *average.*

Answer (score 0):

This would have been more realistic to extend the growth in 18 -24 months

For instance, my friend grew from 155 to 182 cm in 30 months and final height is 187cm

8 cm while age 12: 155 to 163 cm.
14 cm while age 13: 163 to 177 cm.
6 cm in the last 6 months: 177 to 183.
4 cm for the next 2.5 years, 187 cm by 16 year old

Comment: Can you tell us the maximum growth for any 1-year period? I think that's what the OP was asking.